# fullCalendar - remove multiple event IDs with removeEvents

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar to manage a shift plan for multiple employees. For filtering purposes I want to remove events from it according to the selected userID. For each user there is a button providing this ID.

At the moment I make it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./_res/json/getWorkTime.php",  //selects events accoring to the selected user
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",  //data comes as json
    data: {
        start: $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").start._d.dateFormat("Y-m-d"),  //start date of the current view
        end: $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").end._d.dateFormat("Y-m-d"),  //end date of the current view
        user: parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("user_",""))  //userID, coming from the selected button
    }
}).done(function(ret) {
    $.each(ret,function(index,value) { //due to the fact that removeEvents only processes one eventID, running over the result set
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents",value.id);  //getting eventID out of the result set an removing it
    });
});
```

This works perfectly, despite that it takes forever to render the events off the calendar. In numbers this script needs about six seconds to process about 23 entries.

I'm searching for a better and more efficient way to do that. Anyone got ideas?